# Downloading private python package during docker build

Tags: python, docker, github

I'm working on a containerized python application, that has a dependency on a python package hosted in a private github org.  When I'm testing locally, I'm able to download this package by placing the repo url in the requirements.txt file and having pip install it:

git+https://@github.com/my_private_org/python-package.git

However, when I build my docker image, I'm having trouble figuring out what the best way to authenticate with github is, in order for pip to be able to install that package.

I've tried adding my github_token as an environment variable, passing it into the Dockerfile, and cloning it that way like such:

```
# Authenticate with git
ARG GITHUB_TOKEN
RUN echo "machine github.com login $GITHUB_TOKEN" > /root/.netrc

RUN pip install https://@github.com/my_private_org/python-package.git
```

I've also tried just adding the username & token into the github url in the Dockerfile, but that doesn't work and also isn't safe, I was wondering if there were any suggestions on how to go about this?